# Oracle Data warehouse - Handling data that there ins't in any dimension

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

We are implementing a data warehouse and we are stuck in a problem. We want to load this data to fact table(num_class is not a FK/PK);

```
STUDENT     NUM_CLASS   COURSE        CLASS  SHIFT   YEAR   DATE  
----------  ---------   ------------  -----  ------  -----  ----------
   1100882          1   EID           SAD    OT      13/14  28-05-2014
   1100882          1   EID           SAD    PL2     13/14  28-05-2014
```

This is the procedure we use to load the data to fact table:

```
PROCEDURE load_fact_table_presencas IS
      v_source_lines INTEGER;
   BEGIN
      -- JUST FOR STATISTICS
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO v_source_lines
      FROM T_CLEAN_presencas;

      INSERT INTO t_fact_presencas(aluno_id, uc_id,curso_id,turno_id,id_tempo,numero_aula)
      SELECT
         pre.aluno_id,
         uc.uc_id,
         curso.curso_id,
         t.turno_id, 
         ano.id_tempo,    
         pre.numero_aula

      FROM
        t_dim_turnos t,
        T_DIM_ANO_LETIVO ano,
        T_DIM_UCS uc,
        T_DIM_CURSOS curso,
        T_CLEAN_PRESENCAS pre
      WHERE
         -- joins to get dimension keys using sources' natural keys
         ano.data_completa = TO_CHAR( pre."data", 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND 
         NVL(pre.TURNO_ID, pck_error_codes.c_load_invalid_dim_record_Nkey) = t.turno_id_natural AND
         curso.curso_id_natural = pre.curso_id AND 
         uc.uc_id_natural = pre.uc_id AND
         --t.turno_id_natural = pre.turno_id AND
         -- excludes EXPIRED VERSIONS of curso and us dimensions
         uc.is_expired_version = 'NO' AND
         curso.IS_EXPIRED_VERSION = 'NO';


      pck_log.write_log('Info: '||SQL%ROWCOUNT ||' fact(s) (presencas) loaded');
      pck_log.write_log('Done!');
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         pck_log.write_log('Info: No facts generated from '||v_source_lines||' source clean presencas');
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         pck_log.write_log('Error: Could not load fact table (presencas) ['||sqlerrm||']');
         RAISE e_load;
   END;
```

The problem is that some of the data that we want to load isn't at any dimension and when we load the data we give to each row a "special registry". This returns a primary key restriction error because it is possible that all the other keys are the same.

PK is STUDENT_id + COURSE_id + CLASS_id + SHIFT + DATE_id. My dimensions are STUDENT, COURSE, CLASS, SHIFT, DATE.

Comment: can you expand the question a little bit more? What is the PK in your table? what dimensions you have?

Comment: PK is STUDENT_id + COURSE_id + CLASS_id + SHIFT + DATE_id. My dimension  are STUDENT, COURSE, CLASS, SHIFT, DATE.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you would like to know how you would handle values of student, course, class and shift which appear in the fact but not in the dimension tables

Comment: If you want us to help you need to provide more details.  In this case please give us some sample data which causes the problem and explaining *why* it causes a problem.